# how to get updated data to silky smooth marquee jquery plugin

Tags: html, json, jquery

Im trying to update dynamic values to the marquee by using ajax time to time.
Im using following plugin for this
http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

Although the data is actually getting updated it does not get updated into the marquee while scrolling. If I refresh the browser it gets the updated value, that means the ajax update is working fine. What am I doing wrong here?, I need to get the update without stopping the ongoing scrolling of data and without refreshing the browser.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".scroll").marquee();
  var i = setInterval(function (){
     $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : 'http://Data.xhtml',
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(data) {

              var values = '';
              $.each(data, function(i, item) {
              values += '<span class=\'up\'>
                         <span class=\'quote\'>'+data[i].Data+'</span></span>';

              $(".scroll").marquee(values);
              });
        },
      return false;
}, 4000);
});
});

<div class="scroll">
   <span class="up">
        <span class="quote">default value</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".scroll").marquee();
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : 'http://Data.xhtml',
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(data) {
      data=eval(data);
      $.each(data.Data, function(i) { 
        $(".quote").append('<span class=\'up\'><span class=\'quote\'>'+data.Data[i]+'</span> </span>');
      });
    }
  });
}, 3000);
});
<div class="scroll">
  <span class="up">
  <span class="quote">default value</span>
  </span>
```

Comment: Try the above code and Why have you added "return false" in the code

Comment: i tried after removing "return false", but the live scrolling data does not get updated

Comment: try to replace $(".scroll").marquee(values); by $(".scroll").html(values);

Comment: i have already tried that, what happens when that is done is the values get updated but the marquee stops and restarts

Comment: can you provide the link where you are trying to implement this plugin.

Comment: and yes of course you have to have the .html() method to replace html code but its changed again inside the plugin

Comment: the link is in the description of the question, the second line

Comment: What is the response type that you are getting from Data.xhtml? Is it text,XML,JSON,string, array?

Comment: can you show a sample response that you are getting from Data.xhtml page

Comment: Instead of simply posting code, you could explain _how_ your code is supposed to work differently than the OP's.  i.e. - what did you do to fix it?